# Passing array inside script tag in jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I'm trying to pass an array in the below script, but it it not taking as an array. Below is the structure of the hash, that is passed to the jquery-template. options is the array I'm trying to pass

```
{
   "options": [
      [
        "category 1",
        "category 1",
        [
          [
            "subcategory 1",
            "subcategory 1",
            [
              [
                "item 1",
                "item 1"
              ],
              [
                "item 2",
                "item 2"
              ]
            ]
          ],
          [
            "subcategory 2",
            "subcategory 2",
            [
              [
                "item 1",
                "item 1"
              ],
              [
                "item 2",
                "item 2"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
```

I have this code of jquery-template that I'm rendering, when I pass options to the data_tree below, it doesn't take it as an array, instead takes it as non string, which throws error.

```
<script id="nestedFieldTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#div_ff').nested_select_tag({
                initValues: { 
                    "subcategory_val":null,
                    "item_val":null,
                    "category_val":null         
                },
                default_option: "<option value='-1'>...</option>",
                data_tree: ${options},
            });
        });
    {{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
</script>
```

I tried passing it as a normal javascript variable too, but no luck. I would to pass a jquery-template variable as an array in the code below.

Below is the how it is generating the script.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){           
    jQuery('#div_ff_ffs_02').nested_select_tag({            
        initValues: {             
            "subcategory_val":null,             
            "item_val":null,             
            "category_val":null                     
        },              
        default_option: "<option _tmplitem="14"  value='-1'>...</option>",              
        data_tree: category 1,category 1,subcategory 1,subcategory 1,item 1,item 1,item 2,item 2,subcategory 2,subcategory 2,item 1,item 1,item 2,item 2,subcategory 3,subcategory 3,,category 2,category 2,subcategory 1,subcategory 1,item 1,item 1,item 2,item 2,                        
    });       
});
```

Comment: It's very important to line up your braces, or get an editor that matches braces for you. I can't make heads or tails of your array, but I know that it's not an array. It's an object with an array attribute.

Answer (score 0):

By pasting your code into Notepad++, I found an extra brace in the array. Try this:

```
{
    "options": 
    [
        [
        "category 1",
        "category 1",
            [
                [
                "subcategory 1",
                "subcategory 1",
                    [
                        [
                        "item 1",
                        "item 1"
                        ],
                        [
                        "item 2",
                        "item 2"
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                "subcategory 2",
                "subcategory 2",
                    [
                        [
                        "item 1",
                        "item 1"
                        ],
                        [
                        "item 2",
                        "item 2"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Exercise good indentation practices and this problem will occur a lot less.

Comment: made changes accordingly, the array is huge, so edited it before posting here so that it doesn't sideline the context. So, the error is not due to the structure of the array

Comment: Well it was a shot. Are you getting the same error now?

Comment: I have the same error now, as I said the array structure was modified before posting here.

Comment: Ah ok. Have you tried just setting a variable `options = [...];` without the object notation above?

Comment: Its dynamic, so can't set the array there, have to pass it as a variable.